# Buttons not fit in 1 line when resized

Tags: html, css

I have two little html/css problem.

Basically, I have a blue frame (2 div: 1 outer-div for the 1px border and 1 inner-div for the 7px border) which contains a title (top left) a search textbox (top right) and some buttons.

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2Rmx/

We can see the result in full screen here for reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/n2Rmx/embedded/result/

1. First problem: when my browser is maximized, I have my search textbox located at top right and all my buttons fit in one horizontal line. That's ok. But when I resize my browser (the width) I have my buttons fit on two lines and I don't know why?? I would like all my buttons remains in one line.
2. Second problem: when my browser is maximized, my inner-div and outer-div showed correctly. But when my browser is resized (width) at a certain point, the right side of the outer-div is hided by the inner-div and I don't know why??

Any help will be gretly appreciated.

Comment: See my Answer - it should be what you are asking.

Comment: And if you want an explanation for your problems to understand why, see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st question:

If the container is not large enough to display inline elements (as buttons are) they will wrap to the next line. you may use `white-space: nowrap;` on `.inner-div` to prevent that.

2nd

You did specify a `min-width`, so the div will always be at least 700px (740px) wide. If the browser window is not as wide, you will have horizontal scroll bars. The overlapping from the inner div comes from your border and padding definition and the definition of your min-width. Here some math

```
min-width: 700px
border:      7px x 2 (left and right)
padding:    15px x 2 (left and right)
-------------------------------------
           744px > 740px min-width of the outer div
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer to your question as well as on jSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n2Rmx/8/

Pretty much you needed your div that contained your buttons with a width. 
(I also wrapped your *search bar* into a div.)

```
  <div id="search">
      <input type="text" name="SearchCriteria.Anything" />
    </div>


#search { float: right;
   position: relative;
   right: 10px;
   top: -32px;
   outline: none}

input[type="button"] {display:inline;width:100px}
#buttonbar {
    border:4px solid #333;
    clear:both;
    margin:30px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:960px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your css..Change width:auto to width:900px(or whatever);

```
.inner-div
{
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: 7px solid #f3f7fd;
    background-color: #fcfdfe;
    min-width:700px;
    display:block;
}

.outer-div
{
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #bbd8fb;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width:740px;
    display:block;
}
```

and also there is a pblm in this line...

```
<div style="font-size: 1.5em; color: #000; margin-bottom: 10px;">             Recherche d'affaires               </div>
```

remove `margin-bottom: 10px;` and check.it will work..

and i have a suggestion to use table...

```
<table id="buttonbar">
     <tr><td><input type="button" value="this is the first" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the second" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the third" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the fourth" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the fifth" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the sixth" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the seventh" /></td>
     <td> <input type="button" value="this is the eigth" /></td>
    </table>
```

Comment: I need to maintain width:auto because the div width must be the same as the page width. I forgot to mention that when the page is resized I have buttons going back on a new line when the right most button is not reaching the page border but the textbox search border!! I don't know if I'm clear?? Let's try to resize the page and keep attention on right most button. You'll see that this button will go back on a new line for a strange reason...

Comment: Better to use table for buttons.<table><tr><td><input/>...</td></tr></table>